# Local alarm for a foreground service?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-event, android-timer

I have a foreground service and while it's active I want to run some events based on specific exact time that you a user previously set, it can be one time or it can repetitive every day for example.

I don't want to use `AlarmManager` because it triggers system events and you need some permissions for it, I have a running service anyway so why would I  use something like this... So it should lifescoped to the service

I don't want to use `Handler` and its func `postDelayed` or `launch` and `delay` of Coroutines because it's like inventing a wheel, especially when you need to implement logic for repeatable events for a specific time.

So I'm looking something as local broadcast messages but with time configuration like in alarm and I could use set date/time instead of millis delay logic

Answer (score 0):

I might need some more clarifying details to give better advice, but the following should give you an idea of the possible options and their pros and cons.

As much as `AlarmManager` might seem like a pain, it is probably your best bet for something like this, especially if the events are spread out over a longer period as the question hints (e.g. once a day). The alternative would be to use something like `Handler`, Coroutines, or a `TimerTask` inside the service. In addition to introducing the complexities of managing repeating events (as you mentioned), all of these require that the service is constantly running and presumably doing nothing other than waiting to fire an event, which is wasteful and likely not precise over a long period of time. Further, the service could be killed by the system and then you'd have to recreate all the timing logic, whereas `AlarmManager` scheduling is more persistent.

If your foreground service really is active doing other things for the entire duration in which you want these events to fire, or if the requirement is that the events fire if and only if the service is already active, then these options could be back on the table, but I'm not sure without more information.

If exactness is not an issue, you could potentially use `OneTimeWorkRequest` or `PeriodicWorkRequest`; see this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest).

If your main concern with `AlarmManager` is using date/time scheduling instead of milliseconds, that shouldn't be an issue as most temporal classes provide easy ways to convert to milliseconds.

Overall, because of the inherit difficulty of precise scheduling, a system-based implementation like `AlarmManager` is best if exactness is the goal, and other options will incur an unnecessary waste of resources.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: as I said I don't what to use `AlarmManager` because it requires granting permissions

Comment: I understand, but as of now there is no magic solution meeting your requirements. I've listed the alternatives and their pros and cons, but you don't seem to like any of them. This is understandable, but I don't see how else anyone can help.